# can I right turn the p trap?

Tags: plumbing, shower, drain, bathtub, p-trap

I am putting a shower where I have to take a right turn (because of the distance between the p-trap and drain pipe is very small I had to take a right turn) on the top of the p trap to tie into the drain line, would this work? If not, I would need some suggestions

[image]

Comment: I don't see anything wrong except the distance to the drain line is shorter than normal, backflush from the drain line could be a potential problem.

Comment: Thanks, how would I avoid backflush? Any advice?

Comment: I think you can turn the Y (on the drain line) 90 degrees so it points up, then build the connection from there.

Comment: Another way you might be interested in exploring is installing an in-line backflow valve/preventer if space permits.